# Angular 6 - ngFor directive best practice for li iteration?

Tags: angular

My question is pretty amateurish but I'm curious about best use of ngFor. Say I have a component that has some data like this:

```
  stuff = [
    {'id':1,'title':'A'},
    {'id':2,'title':'B'},
    {'id':3,'title':'C'},
    {'id':4,'title':'D'},
    {'id':5,'title':'E'}
  ]
```

And I want to iterate over that and display the title of each item. I have two methods:

```
  <p>Method A</p>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of stuff">
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Method B</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of stuff">{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

One binds to the `ul` and the other binds to the `li` within the ul. From what I can see, they both do the same thing as both lists render on the page. But I feel like this is intuitively wrong.

Is there a "correct" way to iterate a list in Angular? And is there some performance benefit to using one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are **not** equivalent:

- Method A creates as much unorder list tags `<ul>` as the number of items.
- Method B creates list elements `<li>` inside one common `<ul>`.

Both are acceptable, but method B creates less nodes in your DOM, and is closer to a "normal" usage of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

**Method A**

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

etc.
```

**Method B**

```
<p>Method B</p>
<ul>
  <li> item 1 </li>
  <li> item 2 </li>
  etc.
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The element on which you use `NgFor` will keep repeating, see your first example will render like this

```
<ul>
   <li>A</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
...
```

I don't think that's what you want.

If you will put on `li` so only the li will repeat, that's what we want.

```
<ul>
   <li>A</li>    
   <li>B</li>
  .........
</ul>
```

So for UL > Li proper way is to use the NgFor on Li and not on UL

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of stuff">
      {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve performance of your ngFor:

NgFor in Angular comes with the option to override the track by function ([source](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction)). It allows you to choose what property/condition angular should check changes against.

For that, simply add a method to your component like so:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.someUniqueIdentifier;
  // or if you have no unique identifier:
  // return index;
}
```

Whereas in your components HTML you change the loop to:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of stuff; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

[resource](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) for learning more about trackBy.